# How to make a variable in python that can be accessed and modified by any screens in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to make a variable that can be modified by one screen, then the variable can change the text of different screen.
Here is the python file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
import random

value = NumericProperty(0)

class MainWindow(Screen):

    def vval(self, root):
        root.value = 1

    def vvval(self, root):
        root.value = 2

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass
    
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("testing.kv")

class testing(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testing().run()
```

and here is the kivy file

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    GridLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        rows: 2

        Button:
            text: "print 1"
            on_release:
                root.vval(root)
                app.root.current = "second"

        Button:
            text: "print 2"
            on_release:
                root.vvval(root)
                app.root.current = "second"

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    Label:
        text: "successfully printed ", root.value
```

What I expected to happens is when I click one of the button in the the MainWindow, the variable, which I named it "value" will be modified to 1 or 2 depending on what button i click, then the screen changed to the SecondWindow and display the text "successfully printed x", the value of x is depends to the "value" variable.

I'm still new on kivy, if there is some error or ambiguity, I am sorry. Please share me your knowledge about this, it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, one would do this with a **StringProperty** object. The code below shows a working example, although I did take liberties in restructuring some things about your code.  I admit I had some challenges with .bind of the StringProperty which I ended up resolving by building the ScreenManager object in the Python code instead of the .kv lines.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, StringProperty

value = NumericProperty(0)

Builder.load_string('''
<MainWindow>
    name: "main"
    GridLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        rows: 2
        Button:
            text: "print 1"
            on_release:
                # arguments can be passed, including a 'self' of the button object
                app.kv_button("1", "second", self)
                # app.root.current = "second"
        Button:
            text: "print 2"
            on_release:
                # arguments can be passed, including a 'self' of the button object
                app.kv_button("2", "second", self)
                # app.root.current = "second"
<SecondWindow>
    name: "second"
    Label:
        # maps to a StringProperty, root. would be the widget, this is app. which is the App()
        text: app.result_text
''')


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    value: str
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


# Builder.load_file("testing.kv")


class testing(App):
    result_text = StringProperty()

    def kv_button(self, _value: str, next_screen: str, *args):
        print(f"{self} {_value} {args}")
        self.result_text = _value
        # change the screen using the WindowManager object that has been kept as a reference
        self._main.current=next_screen

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._main = WindowManager()
        self._main.add_widget(MainWindow())
        self._main.add_widget(SecondWindow())

    def build(self):
        return self._main


if __name__ == "__main__":
    testing().run()
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir. This helps me a lot in my current work. I will do some modification in your working code to suit my needs. I appreciate you for this knowledge.